# Codeigniter - handle form submission from different controller action

Tags: php, codeigniter

Whats the best way to handle the following situation in codeigniter:

Home controller has an index action and a submit action.

The submit action is used for a form submission.  I want to load the page through the index controller though - including after form submission i.e. with form errors data to repopulate form inputs on error etc.

Whats the best way to do this - without having the index controller handle the main page loading and the form submission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `redirect()`, you won't be able to use [`set_value()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform) for re-populating your form fields.

What's easiest is having your index controller handle both the default load behavior, and the submission.

```
function index()
{
    if($this->input->post('foo'))
    { // something was POSTed
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        //validation rules
    } else
    { // normal view
        //
    }

    $this->load->view('home');
}
```

Alternatively, you can just set up your `index` and `submit` controller, and have them point at the same view, which detects if `validation_errors()` are set and re-populates form fields accordingly.

Third option (hackish): you could use flashdata to keep submission errors and the submitted form values across a redirect back to index. Something like this would work:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('errors', $validation_errors());
```

Comment: so if I have a controller to handle registeration, I should have an if-else where if data posted, then processes registration details. otherwise, just load registration form?

Answer (score 0):

Simply point your form at your submit action:

```
<form method="post" action="/home/submit">
```

Then, use the `submit` action to validate your input before [redirecting](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) back to the `index` action.

Comment: Yes, but how do I get form validation errors and messages etc back to the main index controller ready for loading the main page again.

Comment: So are you suggesting that if my submit action validation fails then I can still use <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> to get the validation errors from the index action?

Comment: No, you'd have to pass those errors back to your `index` action, either using a GET parameter or a session flash variable. If all you're trying to do this for is to avoid the "Resubmit to refresh" problem, the easy solution is to simply handle the submission on the `index` action and redirect the user to `index` when you're done handling that input (again, using a session flash or get parameters to pass that information).