# CodeIgniter add URI Segments

Tags: codeigniter

I have created a login form with CodeIgniter. To test the form, I submit incorrect data, I get the correct information back and the form is redisplayed. If I correct the errors and resubmit the uri segment is appended to the URL.

So I call the app with `localhost/myapp`, the login form is displayed. On submission the url change to `localhost/myapp/controller/authenticate`. When submitting again the URL change to `localhost/myapp/controller/authenticate/controller/authenticate`

What is the problem here?

**View**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>/welcome/authenticate" method="post" id="loginfrm">
<input type="text" name="username" /><?php echo form_error('username', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?><br />
<input type="password" name="password" /><?php echo form_error('password', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

**controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}

public function authenticate()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
    else
    {
        echo $this->input->post('username') . " -->> " . $this->input->post('password');
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Without looking at what functions, how you are using it.... How can we answer? You tell me.

Comment: what is the form action? it should be something like <form action="/controller/authenticate" method="post"> => to make it relative, or if the form is posting back to itself you can leave it blank

Comment: should your paths always include the base_url() function?

Comment: Rooneyl: that is what I have. I have just added the base_url() to the action and that seems to work correctly.

Comment: I hardly ever put it base_url() to my form actions; I like to keep them relative. BTW does you site use index.php or are you rewriting using htaccess?

Comment: no I'm rewriting using htaccess.

Comment: try open the form with: <?php echo form_open('welcome/authenticate); ?>

Comment: @Rooneyl I have updated the post and included the code.

Comment: @Christian at this time I don't want to use the form helper, thanks.

Comment: @user1240182 I take it all is working OK now?

Comment: @Rooneyl well yes and no. I removed the base_url() and it failed. It seems that the root directory is not being included. My config file is correct the base_url is set to localhost/myapp/ but the myapp is not being seen. By the way I'm using the latest version of CI 2.1.0.

Comment: What is the RewriteBase in your htaccess? Is is / or /myapp ?

Comment: @user1240182 - what happens if you change it just /

Comment: @Rooneyl Firefox report that the correct url is called - localhost/myapp/welcome/authenticate but the page displayed is the XAMPP root. Which makes sense I think.

Comment: @Rooneyl I believe that for some reason the base url is being lost. On the first submission of the form all is well however if I resubmit I get a 404 and the path is localhost/welcome/authenticate

Comment: Are you submitting the form to same controller? If so, just leave the `action` parameter blank and you should not have any problem.

Comment: @Broncha sorry but I don't follow. My understanding is that you should call the function to perform the authentication. If I leave the action blank how does the routing work?

Comment: @user1240182 Thats why I asked if you submit the form to same method. I see your problem now. You need to redirect from authenticate, NOT render a view, since it will just keep looping in. Have a look at the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889527/codeigniter-handle-form-submission-from-different-controller-action you will find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Always use redirect in function where forms are processed this prevents the form re-submission in your case if everything works fine and your view is loaded when user tries to refresh the page he will be asked to resubmit the form. Redirect function changes the url in browser address bar so user will no longer be asked for form re-submission.

Comment: I tried this before but the problem is that then the validation errors aren't displayed.

Comment: validation errors are displayed using this method <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> make sure that your form_validation library is loaded in the function where your view is loading.

Comment: I'm using that method as well as <?php echo form_error('username'); ?>

Comment: I think you are missing something visit this link and compare your code with this http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html